# Can converted @PathVariables reference each other?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I've got a Spring `@RequestMapping` with a couple of `@PathVariable`s, and the first one is necessary to narrow down to the second one - you can see in the example below that I need to get the Department in order to get the Module. Using plain `String` `@PathVariable`s I can do it like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/admin/{dept}/{mod}/")
public String showModule(@PathVariable String dept, @PathVariable String mod) {
    Department department = dao.findDepartment(dept);
    Module module = department.findModule(mod);
    return "view";
}
```

But I'm keen to use Spring's `Converter` API to be able to specify the `Department` directly as the `@PathVariable`. So this works after I've registered a custom `Converter` class:

```
@RequestMapping("/admin/{dept}/")
public String showDept(@PathVariable Department dept) {
    return "view";
}
```

But the Converter API doesn't give access outside of the single argument being converted, so it's not possible to implement the `Converter` for `Module`. Is there another API I can use? I'm eyeing up `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` - has anyone solved a problem like this, or are you sticking to String @PathVariables?

I'm using Spring 3.1.

Comment: so you need to know the dept in order to load the module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't done it like this but one way I thought of was to make a separate converter for the both of them:

```
@RequestMapping("/admin/{deptAndModule}/")
public String showDept(@PathVariable DepartmentAndModule deptAndModule) {
    return "view";
}
```

And have the converter able to take an input of the form "deptid-modid" e.g. "ch-c104". It wouldn't be possible to separate them with a slash as the request wouldn't match the RequestMapping pattern of /admin/*/.

In my case, the requirements have changed slightly so that module codes are fully unique and don't need to be scoped to department. So I don't need to do this any more. If I did, I would probably eschew the automatic Module conversion and do it manually in the method.